# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el template reconciliation.line en Odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, widget

Quiero modificar la vista de reconciliación para que tengas los siguientes elementos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ser Odoo 12 he hecho lo siguiente:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<templates>
<t t-extend="reconciliation.line">
        <t t-jquery="caption" t-operation="append">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary o_open_client">Open Client</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary do_pdf">General Ledger</button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Pero no da resultado alguno.

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir el resultado de la foto sería el siguiente código:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="FieldMany2One">
        <t t-jquery="div.o_input_dropdown" t-operation="after">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary o_open_client">Open Client</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary do_pdf">General Ledger</button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Explicación: el template que agrega el input y el enlace no se encuentra en reconciliation.line